# Choosing a name for one of a website's sub-menus

Tags: word-request

I need to enter information of the company profile for three partner companies in a website which belongs to all of these three companies at the same time. What should I name the menu title?
Does the name below sound grammatically correct to you:

> - Company profile **for** / **of**:
>
>   - Alpha Company
>   - Bravo Company
>   - Charlie Company

I doubt which preposition from among the bold ones above is used here normally?
I'm wide open to receive your suggestions.

Comment: I'd just use _Company Profiles_ as the header. If not, then use _for_.

Answer (score 1):

*Company profile* is an OK title for your menu.  While the titles for the elements in the software is chosen, the prepositions are usually omitted.

Comment: Could you provide your reasons for why you think *company profile* is an appropriate name? Maybe the OP won't get the answer unless they're provided a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

While I think you could safely use either, "for" strikes me as the better answer here:

> Company profile *for* Google.

In this use, "for" is being used to indicate purpose or essentially as a synonym for "representing" (See point 7 of [Merriam's definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for)).

On the other hand, though "of" can also be used in the same way, to me it feels like it's suggesting more of an immediate relationship, and doesn't flow as softly as "for" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it depends on the context. I'm leaning towards using *of* here in a professional environment, and in a situation where the website is representing the company. In my honest opinion, it also flows a little better

On the other hand, *for* sounds as if it should be used if the menu is, for instance, in a personal portfolio of yours. For gives the impression of a personal relationship between yu and the company, or as though the profile was a gift to them.

Regardless of the implications, both are grammatically correct in the given use case!